# Python: TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'NoneType'

Tags: python, typeerror, nonetype

My code is:

```
def fact(calc):
    fact = 1
    for z in range(2,calc+1):
        fact = fact * z


epsilon = 10 ** 6
x = float(input())
y = 1
rep = float(x)
while rep < epsilon:
    for i in range(1,999999999,2):
        for j in range (1,2):
            if j == 1:
                a = float(fact(i))
                rep = rep - (x ** i) / a
            else:
                rep = rep + (x ** i) / fact(i)
            if abs(rep) < epsilon:
                break

print(rep)
```

I got an error when I go out from y function with message:

```
a = float(fact(i))
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'NoneType'
```

I can't see what is is wrong on my type.

Comment: `fact` has no return statement, so it returns None.

Comment: I don't understand, at least I fix value equal to 1 ```fact = 1``` so at least I'm waiting 1

Comment: Returning a value from a function requires a return statement.

Answer (score 1):

Fix `fact`, it has no return statement:

```
def fact(calc):
    fact = 1
    for z in range(2,calc+1):
        fact = fact * z
    return fact
```